# Getting error - You should have active texture to use multires baker

Tags: modifiers, uv, texture-baking, baking, multiresolution

I have been struggling to find the actual problem, I have modelled and sculpt Dinosaur and have applied multiresolution modifier and want to bake Normal map. But whenever I try to *Bake*, it's giving me error that "You should have active texture to use multires baker".

[image: screenshot with error]

Solution already tried :

1. Checked if any hidden vertices or mesh. I have selected everything and unwrapped it. I went to edit mode -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (Unhide every thing), Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices -> <kbd>M</kbd> -> Merge by distance and Ensured that everything is selected -> Press <kbd>U</kbd> for unwrap
2. Open UV Editor, create new texture as 4096 x 4096 named it - Normal, Click OK
3. Open Shader Editor, create new material, drag 'Normal' (texture above) to shader editor

Ensure that, object (in edit mode) in viewport is selected, Node (Normal) in shader editor is selected, all vertices are selected, Click on Bake (Bake from multires is checked)

Giving error - You should have active texture to use multires baker

Blend File - [Download (expiry 7 days)](https://easyupload.io/tab4qa)

Comment: Does anything in this post help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94396/unable-to-fix-error-message-you-should-have-an-active-texture-to-use-multires-b?rq=1

Comment: There is something wrong with the material. It has an *Image Texture* node (that should be not connected while baking) and it's selected. But baking completely fails, no matter if it's a *Bake From Multires* or a normal bake. Blender claims there is no image texture ...huh? Fix: create a new material. Add an *Image Texture* node, select the image *Normal-Map*, and select the node to make it active. Finally, press *Bake* and everything works. (tested with Blender 4.0, I have no idea what's wrong with your material.)

Comment: @Blunder - I have already tried by removing and connection between Normal Map (Image Texture) with BSDF and ensure that It is selected before pressing the bake button.  Even I have made another material and texture, nothing happening.. any one pl help

Comment: Hi. I've tried on another computer (Blender 4.0.2). It's the same. Looks like the material is corrupt. Even if I delete all nodes and create a new single *Image Texture* node I get that error. If I just create a new material, add that single node then it works. I have no idea why. -- I would change the Color Space to Non-Color else you get a weird pattern for the flat areas in the normal map. Also the scale is y:1.00044 (=non-uniform). I've applied it and UV unwrapped the model again to make better use of the texture space.

Comment: Here is the compressed file including the baked normal map (4k, RGB, Non-Color): https://easyupload.io/wj7lut (expires in 7 days). Let us know if the bake works with that material. Hope that helps.